# How can I add/update recordset based on dynamic posted input fields?

Tags: asp-classic

I have inherited a classic ASP that has a number of pages each with their own form (and differing) input fields that all post to the same ASP page for processing (adding record or updating record).

I wanted to know if I could dynamically create the database process based on the inputs posted to the processing page. I have tried the following on my `processing.asp` page but it is not working:

```
Dim arrForm, arrInputs
arrForm = Split(request.form,"&")
rs.AddNew
for i = 0 to UBound(arrForm)
    arrInputs = Split(arrForm(i),"=")
    rs(arrInputs(0)) = arrInputs(1)
next
rs.Update
```

Comment: Can you post couple of your forms and the page they are posting to?

Comment: And can you expand on "not working".  Are you getting an error?  Or in what way does the behavior you are getting different what what you expect?

Comment: The `Request.Form` collection already parses values that are passed in the POST body so using `Split()` with `&` isn't going to work. You want to use `For Each key in Request.Form` which returns each Request.Form key value then inside the loop use `value = Request.Form(key)` to return the corresponding value.

Comment: Thanks all, sorry I should have been more specific. The issue I have is not getting the name and value of the posted input field (though thank you @Lankymart for the pointer on `For Each key`) it is inserting a new record into my database with the values. By using either `rs(arrInputs(0)) = arrInputs(1)` or `rs(Item) = Request.Form(Item)` it brings up an `Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal.` error. I would like to know once I have my items and values how to use `addnew` correctly to insert the values into my DB.

Comment: @David So `rs(Item)` would only work if the field in the `ADODB.Recordset` matches the name of the field passed in the form POST. You could try ordinarily, for example `rs(0) =   Request.Form(item)` would add the value of `item` to the first field in the recordset.

Comment: Thanks @Lakymart, it was a rookie mistake that I was posting additional input fields not in the recordset. Upon removing these fields the `addnew` worked. Many thanks to all who helped